# I need to parse a string using javacc containing single quotes as part of the string

Tags: javacc, single-quotes

I have defined grammar rules like

```
TOKEN : { < SINGLE_QUOTE : " ' " > }

TOKEN : {  < STRING_LITERAL : " ' "  (~["\n","\r"])*  " ' ">
```

But I am not able to parse sequences like   're'd' .I need the parser to parse re'd as a string literal.But the parser parses 're' seperately and 'd' seperately for these rules.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
TOKEN : { < SINGLE_QUOTE : "'" > }
TOKEN : {  < STRING_LITERAL : "'"  (~["\n","\r"])*  "'"> }
```

This is pretty much what you had, except that I removed some spaces.

Now if there are two on more apostrophes on a line (i.e. without an intervening newline or return) then the first and the last of those apostrophes together with all characters between should be lexed as one `STRING_LITERAL` token.  That includes all intervening apostrophes.  This is assuming there are no other rules involving apostrophes.  For example, if your file is `'re'd'` that should lex as one token; likewise `'abc' + 'def'` should lex as one token.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I got it working.But the above expressions do not allow backslash(\\) as the last character in the string.How can I modify the expression to allow backslash as the last character in the string?

Comment: It's true that the last character of a STRING_LITERAL can not be a backslash. The last character must be an apostrophe. Same with the first character.  However a backslash can occur at any position other than first and last. For example `'\'` is matched by STRING_LITERAL.  Do you have reason to think otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to lex re'd as STRING_LITERAL token then use the following rule

```
TOKEN : { < SINGLE_QUOTE : "'" > }
TOKEN : {  < STRING_LITERAL : "'"?  (~["\n","\r"])*  "'"?>
```

I didn't see the rule for matching "re" separately.

In javacc, definition of your lexical specification `STRING_LITERAL` is to start with `"'"` single quot. But your input doesn't have the `"'"` at starting.

The `"?"` added in the `STRING_LITERAL` makes the single quot optional and if present only one. so this will match your input and lex as `STRING_LITERAL`.

> JavaCC decision making rules:

1.) **JavaCC will looks for the longest match.**
*Here in this case even if the input starts with the `"'"` the possible matches are `SINGLE_QUOTE` and `STRING_LITERAL`. the second input character tells which token to choose STRING_LITERAL.*

2.) **JavaCC takes the the rule declared first in the grammar.**
Here if the input is only `"'"` then it will be lexed as `SINGLE_QUOTE` even if there is the possible two matches `SINGLE_QUOTE` and `STRING_LITERAL`.

Hope this will help you...